# Standard pattern of initiating and calling the Java method references

Tags: java, design-patterns, standards

I have a `ClassA` object that sets method references inside of `ClassB1` and `ClassB2` objects. `ClassB1` and `ClassB2` objects will later use this method reference while running their methods. But, sometimes we do not set the method reference:

```
public class ClassA {
    public ClassA() {
        ClassB1 objB1 = new ClassB1();
        ClassB2 objB2 = new ClassB2();
        objB1.setFuncitonA(this::functionA);
        objB2.setFuncitonA(this::functionA);
        objB1.functionB();
        objB2.functionB();
    }
    public void functionA(Integer x) {
        x *= 2;
    }
}

public class ClassB1 {
    private Integer intObjB = new Integer(2);
    private Consumer<Integer> functionA = null;
    public void functionB() {
        if(functionA != null) {
            functionA.accept(intObjB);
        }
    }
    public void setFuncitonA(Consumer<Integer> functionA) {
        this.functionA = functionA;
    }
}

public class ClassB2 {
    private Integer intObjB = new Integer(2);
    private Consumer<Integer> functionA = this::defaultFunctionA;
    public void functionB() {
        functionA.accept(intObjB);
    }
    public void setFuncitonA(Consumer<Integer> functionA) {
        this.functionA = functionA;
    }
    public void defaultFunctionA(Integer intObj) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Should it be like in `ClassB1` or like in `ClassB2`, or, does it matter at all? What is the standard pattern of writing such code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nomenclature for this sort of implementation decision:  **lazily instantiating** your field, or **eagerly instantiating** your field.

`ClassB1` lazily instantiates the `functionA` consumer.  This tells a maintainer (including yourself) that this consumer isn't always necessary for every new instance, and  having it `null` in certain contexts is safe.  It *does* mean that you have to look over your shoulder when you're using it though, as in the case of the `null` checks.

`ClassB2` eagerly instantiates the `functionA` consumer.  This tells a maintainer (including yourself) that this consumer is ***required*** at instantiation time.  This means you avoid the silly `null` check if it's truly something you know at instantiation time (and in this case, it *is* something you either know or can get).

The standard pattern then becomes:

- If you're comfortable checking that the field (or variable) is `null` *before* use, then lazily instantiate the field.
- If you *must* be sure that the field (or variable) is not `null` *before* use, then eagerly instantiate the field.

There's no hard and fast rule to use or prefer one over the other.  This will heavily depend on your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent and deep analysis, Makoto. It is much clearer to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating `if` statements is always preferred.

Also, eliminating `null` variables is always better.

Therefore, the `ClassB2` approach is better by far.

Comment: Unless there is a 'null-check' in the setter (or at least treated as nonnullable)

Comment: Thank you very much Mike for your answer, I will accept it, unless we will have some alternative and well supported opinions in this thread in the nearest time. I would greatly appreciate if you give any reference to any book or website where it is written. If you do not have it, it is fine either.